# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.send is not a function

Tags: node.js, api, npm, promise

I am trying to get this aligoapi npm package to work.
when i send request it's showing error

here is my code:

```
const aligoapi = require('aligoapi');
var AuthData = {
  key: '<my_key>',
  user_id: '<my_id>',
}

var send = (req, res) => {
  console.log('check')

  aligoapi.send(req, AuthData)
    .then((r) => {
      console.log('check1')
      res.send(r)
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('check2')
      res.send(e)
    })
}
console.log('check3')

var number = {
  body: {
    sender: '01022558877',
    receiver: '01081079508',
    msg: 'test msg'
  }

}
const result = send(number,'err')
console.log(result)
```

and this is the terminal output:

```
justin@Justinui-MacBookPro examples % node test.js
check3
check
undefined
check2
(node:94270) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.send is not a function
    at /Users/justin/Downloads/node.js_exampl/examples/test.js:19:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:94270) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:94270) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
justin@Justinui-MacBookPro examples %
```

here i notice my request isn't actually being sent because it's returning undefined

Comment: You defined a `send()` function that takes two arguments `(req, res)`, but then you called it like `send(number, 'err')`.  What you passed for `res` was a string.  You can't use that as `res.send()` because the `err` string you passed does not have a `.send()` method.  You HAVE to pass arguments to a function that match the expectations of the function and what it expects those arguments to be.  Usually arguments named `(req, res)` are part of an HTTP request or an Express route handler, not something you create yourself.  It is those an Express route handler that can do `res.send()`.

Comment: How can i clarify what arguments `.send()` expects?

Comment: Well, in plain Javascript, there is no way to enforce typing for arguments.  You can use TypeScript (which compiles to plain Javascript) if you want to enforce type safety.  In plain Javascript, you would use argument naming and comments/documentation to communicate what arguments should be.  You can also implement type checking inside the function in some cases to throw a meaningful exception if you get the wrong type of argument.